# Is there any cameo from previous Step Up films in Step Up: High Water?

Tags: cameo, step-up, step-up-high-water

I recently finished 2 seasons of *Step Up: High Water* and I was wondering if I can spot any cameo from Step Up film series in it but failed to do so. Step Up have a trend of cameos of characters from the previous films and sometimes even in prominent roles. Like Channing Tatum in *Step Up 2:
The Streets* or Adam G. Sevani/Mari Koda in all later films.

So in the same fashion is there any cameo of previous actors in *Step Up: High Water* web series?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no cameos and links to the main series of movies.